# Everytime after updating system, i have to reinstall NVIDIA driver to get my unity work properly

Tags: unity, 13.10, nvidia, graphics, system

Every time after updating system, i have to reinstall NVIDIA driver to get my unity work properly.
Every time i update my system, after restarting top panel and side bar goes missing and graphics acceleration gets disabled, and to fix this i have to reinstall the nvidia driver. Its annoying.

My PC details

Ram = 4GB

Architecture : X86_64

Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad  CPU   Q9300  @ 2.50GHz

NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)

Graphics Driver 331.38 (Downloaded manually from nvidia website)

Linux 3.11.0-15-generic

Ubuntu 13.10 saucy

Xorg version 1.14.5

Comment: Installing graphic drivers manually isn't the best idea. Now you know why. :) Use the one from repository unless you have very good reason not to. And you can also report a bug about this weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Click in the dash, search for software and updates, go to 'install additional drivers' and choose a proprietary driver for your system.

Comment: proprietary drivers are old, and i have the same problem with them as well.

Comment: try adding another user account to ubuntu log in with that see if you have the same problem.

Comment: That didn't help. :'(

Comment: Try this open terminal ctrl+alt+t and type in the following commands then reboot.                                              gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ''

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme ''

gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/theme ''

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ''

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme ''

gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/theme ''